# Storing and fetching user details

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an app that allows multiple user login.Logged in users can store certain details locally and he must view these details next time he log in.
 I did the login part using core data.But i am completely clueless on storing and fetching the detais of a particular user.Please help me out or suggest me a good tutorial for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/) or [other](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started).
I talk to you, what you must doing:
You need to create an entity "User" (for example) in your appDataModel.momd file. To "User" you can add attributes which you need to use later (for example: name, id, age etc.). Now you must create your entity classes User.h and User.m (look tutorials), import User.h to class, where you will create fetch request and create it (fetch request) in some method (look in tutorials). 
To create exemplar of entity:
(User_John for example)

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];

User *User_John = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context]; //create variable of new user
User_John.name=@"John";
User_John.age=23;
User_John.id=1;
```

To change user parameters you need just use setter method:

```
User_John.age=24;
```

OR:

```
[User_John setValue:24 forKey:@"age"];
```